# Quick Sort with Insertion Sort

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I've been working on this code for hours. The goal is to write an optimized QuickSort (with Insertion sort) on an array of pointers (which point to objects that can be compared). Insertion sort is supposed to be used with array sizes < 4.

So far, I have insertion sort working when I pass in an array < 4.

The quicksort is supposed to use the middle index as a pivot, and move everything < the pivot to the left of pivot, and everything > the pivot to the right of pivot.

I'm not even sure my overall approach to quickSort is correct. This is my first attempt at writing a quick sort. I could really use a nudge in the right direction here. The code that's commented out is something I've already tried.

If anything is unclear, let me know. Thanks for the help!

```
void quickSort(Comparable ** array, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
{
    while (fromIndex < toIndex)
    {
        if ((toIndex - fromIndex +1 ) < 4)
        {
            insertionSort(array, fromIndex, toIndex);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            int pivotIndex = partition(array, fromIndex, toIndex);
            quickSort(array, fromIndex, pivotIndex - 1);
            quickSort(array, pivotIndex + 1, toIndex);
        }
    }
}
int partition(Comparable ** array, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
{
    //Comparable *front = array[fromIndex+1];
    int midIndex = (toIndex + fromIndex) / 2;
    //int frontIndex = fromIndex;
    //Comparable *back = array[toIndex - 1];
    //int backIndex = toIndex - 1;
    //Comparable *compare = front;
    //int compareIndex = frontIndex;

    SortFirstMiddleLast(array, fromIndex, midIndex, toIndex);
    swap(array, midIndex, toIndex - 1);
    int pivotIndex = toIndex - 1;
    Comparable * pivot = array[pivotIndex];
    int indexLeft = fromIndex + 1;
    int indexRight = toIndex - 2;

    bool sortFinished = false;
        while (*array[indexLeft] < *pivot)
        {
            indexLeft++;
        }
        while (*array[indexRight] > *pivot)
        {
            indexRight--;
        }
        if ((*array[indexLeft] >= *pivot) && (*array[indexRight] <= *pivot))
        {
            if (indexLeft < indexRight)
            {
                swap(array, indexLeft, indexRight);
                indexLeft++;
                indexRight--;
                sortFinished = true;
            }
        }
            if (sortFinished == true)
            {
                swap(array, pivotIndex, indexLeft);
                pivotIndex = indexLeft;
                return pivotIndex;
            }

//  ++frontIndex; // advance to next element
//  while (*array[frontIndex] < *array[backIndex])
//  {
//      // search forward for out of order element
//      while ((*array[frontIndex] < *array[backIndex]) && (*array[fromIndex] > *array[frontIndex]))
//          ++frontIndex;
//      //search backward for out of order element
//      while ((*array[frontIndex] < *array[backIndex]) && (*array[compareIndex] <= *array[backIndex]))
//          --backIndex;
//      swap(array, frontIndex, backIndex);
//  }
//  //insert mid position comparison element
//  if (*array[compareIndex] >= *array[frontIndex])
//  {
//      swap(array, fromIndex, frontIndex);
//      returnValue = frontIndex;
//  }
//  else
//  {
//      swap(array,fromIndex, (frontIndex - 1));
//      returnValue = (frontIndex - 1);
//  }
//  return returnValue;
}
void swap(Comparable ** array, int swapIndex1, int swapIndex2)
{
    Comparable * temp = array[swapIndex1];
    array[swapIndex1] = array[swapIndex2];
    array[swapIndex2] = temp;
}

void SortFirstMiddleLast(Comparable ** array, int fromIndex, int midIndex, int toIndex)
{ 
    // first must be less than mid, must be less than last
    if (*array[fromIndex] > *array[midIndex])
    {
        swap(array, fromIndex, midIndex);
    }
    if (*array[fromIndex] > *array[toIndex - 1])
    {
        swap(array, fromIndex, toIndex - 1);
    }
    if (*array[midIndex] > *array[toIndex - 1])
    {
        swap(array, midIndex, toIndex - 1);
    }
}
void insertionSort(Comparable ** array, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
{
    for (unsigned i = fromIndex + 1; i < toIndex; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if (*array[j] < *array[j - 1])
            {
                swap(array, j, j-1);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and we expect you to show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: There is one path through `partition` that doesn't return a value. If you take that path the program is undefined.